# How text in HTML ordered list can be emphasized?

Tags: html

> I am trying to solve the reason that the unit test on testdome.com failing >my HTML code.
>   The output seems to be all right.
>
> The URL of the task: https://www.testdome.com/Questions/HtmlCss/Inspector/6932?testId=13&testDifficulty=Easy
>
> I am getting message: Lists and images: Wrong.

```
<ol>
    <li><em><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></em></li>
    <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
</ol>

<ul>
    <li>New logo:</li>
    <img src="new_logo.gif" />
    <li>Old logo:</li>
    <img src="old_logo.gif" />
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Omit the end slash from the img tag and add an alt tag. Also, enclose the img tag within the li tags (so you have 2 list items instead of 4 - the names with the images underneath is how it's currently coded).  Then you should be ok.

Sample :

```
<ol>
  <li><em><a href="#logo">Company's logo</a></em></li>
  <li><a href="#employees">List of employees</a></li>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>New logo:<img src="new_logo.gif" alt="new logo"></li>
  <li>Old logo:<img src="old_logo.gif" alt="old logo"></li>
</ul>
```